# Firebase no such instance field 'databaseReference'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to get all the data from my database as a list, I get the following error from debugger and the code returns a null List.

```
public static DbOps get(Context ctx) {
    if (sDbOps == null) {
        sDbOps = new DbOps(ctx);
    }
    return sDbOps;
}

private DbOps(Context ctx) {
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    if(mProducts == null) {
        getProducts();
    }
}



public List<Product> getProducts() {
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Product pr = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                mProducts.add(pr);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return mProducts;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you created your `dbRef` variable

Comment: @SushinPv in the constructor

Comment: Create the dbRef variable in the main class as private and initialize it in the onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are `trying to access a variable that is not declared in the scope of that function`.

To solve this, a simple solution is that, make the variable as private or public member of that class so that all member functions can access it.

Example

```
public class classname{
    private FirebaseDatabase dbRef;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    }

   //Or initialize in your own function
    private DbOps(Context ctx) {
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
        if(mProducts == null) {
           getProducts();
        }
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Product pr = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                    mProducts.add(pr);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return mProducts;
    }
}
```